# Programatically return to previous ViewController in different storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I tried many answers here but none of them had the same exact scenario.

I'm trying to navigate to a `UIViewController` that's within a separated storyboard in a different bundle, so far I was able to navigate to it but am unable to return to the previous `UIViewController`. The method that invokes the external view controller (`TabBarController`) is implemented as follows:

```
+(void) launchExternalUI: (UIViewController *) previousViewController {
    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: [self frameworkBundle]];
    TabBarController *vc = (TabBarController*) [sb instantiateInitialViewController];  
    [previousViewController.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

Now the method within `TabBarController` that should return to the previous view controller:

```
- (void) navigateToPreviousViewController: (UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In `TabBarController`, if I print all the viewcontrollers within `self.navigationController`, all I see is the `TabBarController`, shouldn't I see the previous view controller that pushed this on `launchExternalUI` ? The `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` has no effect at all. I'm a bit lost on this.

It's also important to notice that `previousViewController` is defined in a local storyboard and  `TabBarController` is implemented in a different `.framework`, would that cause the issue?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

****Edit:** The navigation flow I need is `storyboard1:VC1->storyboard2:VC2->storyboard1:VC1`, I can get `storyboard1:VC1->storyboard2:VC2` part to work but not `storyboard2:VC2->storyboard1:VC1`

Comment: What class is the launchExternalUI method in? What is previousViewController?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's a class method defined in a Utils class (NSObject) within the .framework.

Answer (score 3):

I often split projects up into various Storyboards, and have created a dynamic view controller that handles the task of loading the appropriate controller from a secondary storyboard, whilst maintaining the navigation tree.

I've created a sample project and uploaded to github as it's easier than explaining all the steps here. The key part to note is the User Defined Runtime Attributes for each of the DynamicStoryboardViewControllers in the Main.stoyboard. Note also that each of the secondary storyboards need the "is initial View Controller" checked for one of your viewControllers. Not included in the example is loading a specific scene from a storyboard. This is no more than adding the "sceneName" dynamic runtime attribute much in the same way as the storyboardName attribute is added.

it's a quick sample so a little rough, but you'll get the idea of how it all works. Feel free to ask questions if you get stuck.

Cheers!

EDIT:

It dawned on me that perhaps you don't have a navigationController in the view hierarchy (as i do in my sample). And in any event, seemingly, you won't have much control over where your tab bar is introduces. So without a navigationController the [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] won't work;

You should test for this and either call the popViewControllerAnimated as you do, or call dismissViewControllerAnimated ;

```
  if(self.navigationController){
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }else{
      [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:Yes completion:nil];
  }
```

Hope this helps, if not, perhaps you can supply some sample code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm gonna try this out. But I have to mention it is amazingly frustrating that there's no way of doing this without quite some hacking, I would assume either I'm completely wrong on the way I'm reusing functionality in my project (by creating separated .frameworks), or apple is really expecting developers to copy-paste and do a bunch of re-work by keeping refactoring storyboards to have everything in one storyboard ALWAYS. Something that android magically solves by having a simple back-button has to be totally hacked in iOS.

Comment: OK, from what I understood you're defining a few dynamic storyboards on your Main.storyboard and you're dynamic loading them out of singleViewControllerSB and tabbarControllerSB. In my case, I don't want to have to define on the MainStoryBoard that I'll link to different storyboards, all I needed to do is to programatically start a viewcontroller from a different storyboard and be able to return to the view controller that called it after I'm done with it, is this not possible?

Comment: No, i'm creating a dynamic view controller, passing the name of the storyboard i want to navigate to in the runtime attributes. And yes, it's possible as my sample demonstrates.

Comment: OK, but can't I do this without having to tell my customer that in order to integrate with my framework they'll have to change their app's main storyboard to create a dynamic view controller so that I'm able to navigate back to their viewcontroller after the user is done with my viewcontroller? Why a simple dismiss wouldn't take me back to the previous view controller regardless of where and how it's defined?

Comment: Ok, now get a better picture of your contraints. You should note that in launchExternalUI, you're passing a tab bar controller to the previousViewController's navigation controller. As per the Docs for pushViewController, The parrameter passed should be a UIViewController, it states "The view controller to push onto the stack. This object cannot be a tab bar controller." this may be why your navigation gets screwed up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the follow up, I see what you're saying. So bottom line is I can't provide a framework which has a storyboard having a TabBarController as initial view controller, is there any known work around for this?

Comment: Yes you can, you simply cant push it in the way you are trying to do, look at the dynamicStoryboardViewController and my sample and you'll see that the tabViewController is added as a child in viewdidload. Follow the else; this is the code that gets called if the controller being added is a Tab bar. Adapt your launchExternalUI accordingly

Comment: Thanks, will try that and will let you know!

Comment: Ok, by using the same approach you had on `viewdidload` I was able to navigate **to** the second view controller, now on to my original question on this post, how do I return back to the previous view controller that loaded it?

Comment: @MDB983 Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create an unwind segue within your original view controller, and use segues instead of pushing/popping view controller views onto the view array.

To create an unwind segue you should create an unwind method in the ORIGINAL viewcontroller:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToOriginalViewControllerSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender {
    ; //TODO: anything special you need, reference via sender
}
```

Then, in your NEW viewcontroller, in the storyboard, drag from the controller icon to the Exit icon.  Link that to the Unwind segue you named above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the only problem here is that the NEW view controller is contained within a .framework that is meant to be distributed throughout the team to integrate in different projects and should require minimum setup. I would expect there would be an easier way to dismiss the current ViewController and return to the previous one regardless of how it's structured (really miss android's back button here).

Comment: Checking some basics: did you assign a name to your views in each storyboard?

Comment: Yes I have, but the ViewController inside the framework doesn't necessarily needs to know who called it, it should be able to dismiss itself and go back to the previous view without that information, like android's back button magically does for you. I may be wrong but I think the fact that the 2nd ViewController is loaded from a storyboard located in a different bundle in a different .framework may be the cause of the issue? Once again thank you for the follow up, really appreciated!

Comment: I was able to return to the previous UIViewController by passing down a reference of it to the second viewcontroller and then from the second viewcontroller doing as follows:
    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    window.rootViewController = self.previousViewController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
But that's actually wrong for various reasons.

Comment: Any further thoughts on this? your input is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController * YourViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Storyboard Identifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:YourViewController animated:TRUE];
```